# reveal.js speaker notes not working

Tags: reveal.js

The speaker notes work on the default reveal.js presentation.

On my presentation as soon as I add the notes.js dependencies the presentation stops working at all.

I have no idea what might be causing this issue.
I tested moving the default presentation index.html to my presentation folder and it works, so that rules out any problem on the other files I have.

What might be triggering this issue? What parts of my code should I share?

And having the thesis presentation in just some days is not helping me find the issue.

Comment: Check your browser's JavaScript error console.

Comment: Failed to load resource: http://localhost:63342/Presentation/lib/js/head.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
reveal.js:346 Uncaught ReferenceError: head is not defined

Comment: Then your answer would appear to lie here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377010/multiplex-functionality-with-reveal-js-slides (Reveal.js relies on Head.js - http://headjs.com/). Always check your JS console.

Comment: That fixed the issue. It was indeed a mistake in the code that I missed. It was loading head.js instead of head.min.js. Have a virtual Beer on me!

Answer (score 1):

Notes.js is now part of the plugins for reveal js, to get speaker notes working register the plugin using:

```
<script src="plugin/notes/notes.js"></script>
    <script>
      Reveal.initialize({
        plugins: [ RevealNotes ]
      });
    </script>
```

The notes.js package can be found in the plugin folder for reveal.js master which can be downloaded from: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/archive/master.zip